# get best round score ( max score and min second) in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, max

I have a sheet that include 7 columns: ( name , score1 , time1, score2 , time2 , score3 , time3).
I want to select best round score provided that first find best score( max score), if there are 2 rounds include max score , then select the rounds that include best time ( min time).

like below table ( get final score and final time):

| name | score1 | time1 | score2 | time2 | score3 | time3 | final_score | final_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 100 | 20 | 90 | 10 | 100 | 19 | 100 | 19 |
| name 2 | 10 | 40 | 50 | 15 | 25 | 2 | 50 | 15 |

In `max` formula we have one condition and I don't know how can I do this...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (as table within your question, eg. using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) and your expected result. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: So, if you scroll through the list of Excel functions you should find LARGE() and that will give you the first, second or third or nth value based on the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

`Best Score` it's easy because it will always be the max score of the corresponding columns. The tricky part is the time associated to a specific max score. I've used the headers value to locate the time columns based on your input

[image]

Formula for best score is: `=MAX(B2;D2;F2)`

Formula for best time is: `=MIN(IF(B2:F2=$I2;IF(LEFT($C$1:$G$1;4)="time";C2:G2)))`

Just drag down.

**NOTE**: The formula for best time is **an array formula** so it must be entered using <kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it won't work!

Also, notice my argument separator is `;` so you may need adapt that part

Comment: thanks a lot, can you send your sample file?
i'm try your formula, but not success

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use these formulas:

```
=MAX(FILTER(A2:G2,LEFT($A$1:$G$1, 5) ="score" ))
=SMALL(FILTER(A2:G2,LEFT($A$1:$G$1, 4) ="time" ),2)
```

[image]

`FILTER` returns the according values for score or time.
Then `MAX` and `SMALL` are applied to achieve the results you need.

If you don't have Excel 365 you will have to select each column individually for the first range:

```
=MAX(B2,D2,F2)
=SMALL((C3,E3,G3),2)
```

Comment: thanks for reply
i'm using excel 2010, i try your formula, but its not work correct. 
for example:

score1 = 80
time1 = 40
----------
score2 = 80
time2 = 50
----------
score3 = 40
time3 = 49
----------
your formula return :
score_final : 80
time _ final : 49

Comment: What would be your expected result?